# Whatsapp limiting network usage?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, data-monitoring

Someone I know has recently registered with Whatsapp and has been a heavy user of Video chats and other bandwidth heavy features. Today they've had an issue with sending and receiving messages, and got some kind of warning about network usage (I've not actually seen the warning).

I checked in the Network usage settings / statistics and the user has managed to send and receive a whopping 1GB (respectively) within one week :P. Does Whatsapp impose some kind of restriction on the usage of its network with regard to data usage? I'd just like to be able to work out whats causing the error, and how the user can best handle it :).

Thanks for any clues and your time, regards!

P.S. I have sent an email to Whatsapp's support, but I reckoned I might get a quicker response here :P !

Comment: Please state clearly what warning you get and also make sure that's from WhatsApp.

Answer (score 1):

There was and possibly still is a [restriction on message forwarding](https://time.com/5508630/whatsapp-message-restrictions/) but there is none on data usage.

> WhatsApp has announced it will restrict the number of times an individual message can be forwarded.

The only [restriction on video](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/iphone/30060668/) is about the size. When it is larger than 16MB then you need to reduce it.

> If you choose to send an existing video, it is limited to 16 Megabytes. On most phones, this will equal about 90 seconds to three minutes of video. If you choose an existing video that is larger than 16 MB, then you will have the option to trim the length of the video before sending it.

You should check if data limit is set or not on the phone. Go to Settings -> Data usage -> Cellular data usage. Clicking the gear, should show you the data limit and if it was set or not.

Comment: That 16MB limit is also enforced at device level which can be changed with root. All you have to do is `sed -i 's/"media_limit_mb" value="16"/"media_limit_mb" value="1000"/' /data/data/com.whatsapp/shared_prefs/com.whatsapp_preferences.xml`.

Comment: @IrfanLatif You are correct. Unfortunately I don't think the OP nor his friend have rooted devices. I might be wrong though.

Comment: Right. But the point is that 16MB limit too doesn't give *some kind of warning about network usage*.

Comment: @IrfanLatif True. That's why I wrote restriction and not warning on the video part.